# Using CanExecute in RelayCommand MVVM Toolkit

Tags: xaml, mvvm, command, toolkit, winui

I have bound button command to one `RelayCommand` from `MVVM Toolkit`, which executes some function, with following:

```
[RelayCommand]
private async void SomeMethod() {}
```

I want to prevent multiple clicks on the button hence, preventing multiple method calls via `CanExecute` parameter of `RelayCommand`, but I can't figure that one out.

I know that `RelayCommand` first checks with `CanExecute` if it is possible to execute the command, but I do not understand how to go about implementing it.

I have searched numerous questions on the topic but could get nowhere near to solution.

Edit: Also there is no `SomeMethod.isRunning` property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To implement `CanExecute`, You can try the following example:

```cs
[RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(IsSomeMethodExcutable))]
private async void SomeMethod(){}

private bool IsSomeMethodExcutable() { return _isBusy;}
```

Comment: I believe that this should be the accepted answer.  The RelayCommand has the correct signature `private async void` and adding the _CanExecute_ parameter specifies the method to call when the **CanExecute** state changes.    The only other thing needed is to call `SomeMethodCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();` in a method that changes the state of `_isBusy`